# What is the variation of ammeter reading with PQ

Tags: voltage-divider

Honestly, this is a homework question. A screenshot of it is given below:

[image: Variable Voltage Divider]

Okay these are the things I have done in order to take the answer.

1. First I calculate the equivalent resistance which comes form 1000 ohms and 10 ohms.
2. Therefore I assume that total resistance of the circuit is increasing.
3. And since the potential difference is constant for the equivalent resistance, I get the relationship of current is indirectly proportional to resistance by using Ohm's law.

So according to my argument a graph should indicate a decrement of current with distance PQ, but here in the answer I don't have such a thing. So I think I have done something wrong, so that is why I'm asking this question here!

Comment: If you move X upwards, I'd say the QX decreases (resistance is directly proportional to length).This will come in series with a parallel combo of XP and 10 ohm. Tip : You can find this equivalent resistance ( Qx + ( Px || 10) ) and differentiate it to check the slope.

Comment: Your pathway seems a longcourse

Comment: Its a path to sucess !! :P

Comment: Try a couple of examples: What is the current when X=P? What is it when X=Q? What is it when X is halfway between P and Q? You'll eventually see a pattern that resembles one of the graphs.

Comment: could you say the which path that the current will take when X=P

Answer (score 1):

When the wiper is at P the resistance is (0Ω || 10Ω) + 1000Ω = 1000Ω. At Q it is 1000Ω || 10Ω ~= 10Ω. Therefore the resistance *decreases* as the wiper moves from P to Q, and subsequently the current increases. Therefore all graphs are potentially correct.

In order to determine *which* of the graphs is correct, write out the equation for the current in terms of the resistance and wiper position and plot it.

Comment: How can you say "the wiper is at P the resistance is (0Ω || 10Ω) + 1000Ω = 1000Ω. At Q it is 1000Ω || 10Ω ~= 10Ω." Note:I get the calculation you have done but  how do you take that, I mean what is theory behind that?

Comment: That's how a potentiometer is constructed; part of the resistance is between one terminal and the wiper, and the rest is between the wiper and the other terminal. When the wiper is all the way at each end the resistance to the closest terminal is (nominally) 0Ω, and the resistance to the further terminal is the full rating.

Comment: Okay, when the wiper is at P  form which path would the current travel, how to determine it?

Comment: By thinking about it. The path would be through both the bare wire and the 10Ω resistor into the wiper, and then through the 1000Ω of the pot.

Comment: So why you didn't take the equivalent resistance between 1000 ohms and that 10 ohms resistor which is parallel with 1000 ohms when wiper is at  P?

Comment: The 10Ω is not in parallel with the whole pot, only the resistance between P and X. When the wiper is at P, that resistance is 0.

Comment: Oh I see,you are  exactly correct. But I'm confused with this thing, if the current flows from both 1000 ohms and 10 ohms, when the wiper at P , why didn't you take that 10 ohm resistor  for this calculation ((0Ω || 10Ω) + 1000Ω)

Comment: 0Ω || 10Ω is equal to 0Ω.

Comment: Ya of course, I know that thing .But What I want to know is why you neglect the 10 ohm resistor which is parallel to 100 ohm resistor for the instance when the wiper is at P?

Comment: What 100Ω resistor?

Comment: I beg your pardon It is not 100 it  should be 10 ohms

Comment: Oh, the one at the top? Didn't notice it. Just add it into the equation.

Comment: The 10Ω at top is insignificant when you have 1000Ω.  You can ignore it at the start.  As wiper gets close to 100%, it must be there.  Look at wiper positions.  I'd do 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.  Graph it out.  So 0%, (0Ω || 10Ω) + 1000Ω (+ 10Ω).  Calculate current for 10V.  25%, (250Ω || 10Ω) + 750Ω (+ 10Ω). Current.  You should be able to figure it out from there.